# executar python em outra máquina

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal é possível executar um script python em outra máquina da rede?

Exemplo: Uso a máquina dev01 e preciso executar um script para coleta e dados na maquina BD03 ambas as maquinas tem o python instalado e tudo certinho, pretendo fazer isso pois o meu LAB tem 1 vm banco e 1 vm dev (ai queria rodar alguns script "remotamente" de um Linux parea um Windows e vise e versa

Comment: Não consegue conectar via SSH?

Comment: Então, o problema é que é uma maquina Windows Server e as vezes é um debian sacas? Pensei em fazer algo meio que automatico onde da minha maquina eu possa coletas as informações sem ter que acessar... Como se fosse um "execute=192.168.0.18" (executar na maquina x entendeu?)

Comment: Você pode usar o Ansible para tal.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais "straightforward" de fazer isso é simplesmente usar ssh  - você deixa a máquina onde quer executar o comando pré-configurada, e aceitando conexão por chaves criptográficas de uma identidade de onde você vai conectar, e passa o comando a ser executado (python seguido do nome do script), direto na linha de comando do ssh.

Tudo coisa que não funciona no windows!

Então, em vez de instalar coisas pra subir e reconfigurar 30 anos de história do Unix/Linux por dentro do Windows - o que é possível, mas deixa de ser a forma mais fácil, o melhor mesmo é ter um sisteminha em Python que receba de alguma forma o comando que você quer e execute-o - ou diretamente, chamando funções dentro dele mesmo, ou como processos externos.

Tem algumas abordagens pra isso - em comum em todas elas é que vai ter um processo Python, escutando em alguma porta da máquina, direta ou indiretamente, executando o que você quer.

Uma das formas é usando [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) - celery é mais usado para executar tarefas demoradas como parte de sistemas web - sem que quem estiver usando o sistema pela web tenha que esperar a tarefa . Mas  isso é possível por que ele torna extremamente simples você chamar uma função quase como se fosse uma chamada normal do Python, e ela é executada em outro computador da rede. É mais usado para processamento paralelo do que para executar tarefas específicas em máquinas específicas no entanto - e talvez dê bastante trabalho configurar o celery para isso.  (Tipo "preciso que alguém calcule isso", e um dos workers do celery, em qualquer máquina que estiver configurada vai lá e executa é o uso mais normal).

Outra forma é usar [xmlrpc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) ou jsonrpc  - veja as docuemtnações na biblioteca padrão do Python mesmo sobre xmlrpc - é simplezinho deixar um programa rodando com uma função que vai ser chamada remotamente de outro programa Python.  Lembre-se, em Python 3 de passar sempre byte-strings como parâmetro.

Outra forma é fazer uma camadinha usando Flask com views para chamar cada tarefa que você quer executar - aí, dos computadores remotos, você só precisa acessar as urls específicas. Essa forma não exige que você tenha um programa em Python na máquina cliente, de onde vai mandar executar os comandos - e na verdade é bem simples: veja o que função faz "tudo o que você precisa" no computador alvo, vá [num tutorial de Flask](https://pythonspot.com/flask-hello-world/) e faça até o "hello world", e, insira, antes da linha `return "hello world!"`,  uma chamada para a função que faz o que você quer executar. Pronto.